# android - build variants ID

Tags: android, upgrade, build-variant

I've app in several build variants. One of the variants is `global`, the others `local.`

I don't want support the "local" variants any more. Is it possible (in google play store or in app) set that a `global` variant should be used for the upgrade?

> **Gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'cz.gb.ps.general'
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 246
        versionName "1.1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions("version")
    productFlavors {
        cr {
            applicationId "cz.gb.ps.general"
            dimension "version"
            versionNameSuffix "-CR"
        }
        brn {
            applicationId "cz.gb.ps.brn"
            dimension "version"
            versionNameSuffix "-BRN"
        }
        // ...
    }
    sourceSets {
        cr.java.srcDir 'src/cr/java'
        brn.java.srcDir 'src/brn/java'
        // ...
    }
}

task prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel {

}

dependencies {
    def support_version = "28.0.0"
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You can't do it via Google Play because If you want the "local" variants to upgrade to the "global" variant they must have the same application id.

Comment: Post your gradle file

Comment: graddle file added